# I cannot delete files on IRIX 6.2

Tags: filesystems, root, accounts, irix

I started using IRIX 6.2 so I could do some Nintendo 64 Development for the IRIX community.

WARNING: IT IS A VERY WEIRD SITUATION! Also, I am using root.

The file manager GUI states that the files that exist do, in fact, exist in the directory.

The console states that all of these files exist as well when I type "ls" into the console in the "/" directory.

I can delete, move, copy, and link files from the console. However, when I go to the files in the file manager GUI and right click on the folders, it says that `<file name> does not exist`. This also happens when I try to copy and link these files.

I have tried logging into other accounts on my computer (such as the guest or demo accounts), but I still get the same errors.

I have also tried asking other people on the IRIX forums and the IRIX discord, but they don't really know what the problem is.

[Here](http://forums.irix.cc/thread-1288.html) is where you can find that forum post, although nobody really knows what to do as I have tried what they have said.

Does anyone here have any answers or ideas of what the problem could be?

Posted on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/IRIX/comments/c32j7e/irix_62_filesystem_issues/0

The output I get when I do ls -l:

```
-rw-r--r--    1 root     sys          167 Oct 11 12:14 .Sgiresources
-rw-r--r--    1 root     sys         1085 Sep 30 05:35 .acrorc
-rw-r--r--    1 root     sys          601 Sep 25 09:11 .cshrc
drwxr-xr-x    6 root     sys         4096 Oct 11 12:26 .desktop-IRIS
drwxr-xr-x    5 root     sys         4096 Oct 12 18:31 .desktop-RYAN
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     sys            9 Sep 25 17:06 .ebtpriv
-rw-r--r--    1 root     sys          704 Sep 25 09:11 .login
-rw-r--r--    1 root     sys          446 Oct 12 11:20 .neditdb
drwx------    3 root     sys         4096 Oct 11 12:28 .netscape
-rw-r--r--    1 root     sys          638 Sep 25 09:11 .profile
-rw-r--r--    1 root     sys           30 Oct  8 18:11 .sgihelprc
-rw-r--r--    1 root     sys           41 Oct 11 12:04 .syserr
-rw-r--r--    1 adm      adm          885 Sep 25 09:11 .varupdate
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     sys           55 Sep 27 17:29 .webcache
-rw-r--r--    1 root     sys          100 Sep 30 05:35 .weblink
-rw-r--r--    1 root     sys          296 Sep 25 16:49 .webspace-preferences
-rw-r--r--    1 root     sys           73 Sep 25 12:30 .wshttymode
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     sys            9 Sep 27 17:28 APPS
-rw-r--r--    1 root     sys      59153408 Sep 27 17:25 Apps.tar
-rw-r--r--    1 root     sys      467197952 Sep 27 19:03 IDO6.2.tar
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     sys            9 Sep 27 19:30 MIPSPro
-rw-r--r--    1 root     sys      21200896 Sep 26 18:25 Mips.tar
-r--r--r--    1 root     sys        82160 Oct  8 14:54 Models
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     sys           45 Sep 28 19:32 Nedit
drwxr-xr-x    8 root     sys          125 Sep 26 18:26 OS2.0K_FULL_PAK
drwxr-xr-x    9 root     sys         4096 Oct 11 19:26 OS20I
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     sys           24 Sep 27 10:37 TestGame
-rw-r--r--    1 root     sys        83496 Oct  9 14:13 av8b.flt
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root     sys            7 Sep 25 09:11 bin -> usr/bin
-rw-r--r--    1 root     sys        83496 Oct  9 14:13 boris1.flt
-rw-r--r--    1 root     sys        83510 Oct  9 14:23 borisman.flt
-rw-r--r--    1 root     sys            0 Oct  9 17:19 cradle.aifc
-rw-r--r--    1 root     sys      11805772 Oct  9 17:07 cradle.aiff
-rw-r--r--    1 root     sys      3212230 Oct  2 17:03 cradle.mp3
-rw-r--r--    1 root     sys          396 Oct  9 17:15 cradle.table
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root     sys            4 Sep 25 12:28 debug -> proc
drwxr-xr-x   16 root     sys        12288 Oct 12 12:28 dev
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     sys           27 Oct  1 17:47 dumpster
drwxr-xr-x   14 root     sys         4096 Oct 12 12:28 etc
-rw-r--r--    1 root     sys       665600 Oct  9 16:07 freeglut-2.4.0-2.tgc-irix6.2-mips3-tgcware.tardist
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     sys        45364 Sep 28 02:27 gl
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     sys         4096 Sep 27 19:09 help
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     sys           33 Sep 27 17:29 insight
-rw-r--r--    1 root     sys      329195520 Sep 28 07:02 irix-development-foundation-1.2-for-irix-6.2.tardist
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     sys           72 Sep 27 11:13 lib
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     sys           39 Sep 27 11:13 lib32
-rw-r--r--    1 root     sys        91344 Oct  9 14:26 monkey.flt
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     sys         4096 Oct 12 11:20 n64game
-r-xr-xr-x    2 244      user     1275560 Jun 12  2002 nedit
-rw-r--r--    1 root     sys      1218560 Oct  9 16:07 nedit-5.5-2.tgc-irix6.2-mips3-tgcware.tardist
drwx------    2 root     sys           23 Sep 25 16:57 nsmail
drwxr-xr-x    8 root     sys          101 Sep 27 09:06 opt
-rw-r--r--    1 root     sys      117053440 Sep 26 16:58 os20k.tar
-rw-r--r--    1 root     sys           14 Oct 11 17:37 password
dr-xr-xr-x    2 root     sys         9264 Oct 12 18:40 proc
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     sys        46172 Sep 28 02:27 pt
drwxr-xr-x   29 root     sys         4096 Sep 27 19:10 relnotes
-rw-r--r--    1 root     sys           35 Oct 11 12:27 root.home
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     sys         4096 Sep 25 11:17 sbin
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     sys           20 Sep 25 09:11 stand
-rwxr-xr-x    1 OutOfBox demos       1048 Sep 25 09:34 systemtour
drwxrwxrwt    4 sys      sys           73 Oct 12 18:30 tmp
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     sys      3541908 Oct 12 12:27 unix
drwxr-xr-x   35 root     sys         4096 Oct 12 12:28 usr
drwxr-xr-x   26 root     sys         4096 Sep 27 17:32 var
```

Comment: Are they broken symlinks? Could you import the details from those other posts into this one so that Answerers have it in front of them?

Comment: I am more of a beginner: what are those, Jeff?

Comment: Jeff, do you know how I could tell that? I am more of an IRIX beginner haha!

Comment: The output of `ls -l` in the directory with these files would be good. Format the output in an [edit to your post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/526139/edit) by highlighting the output and clicking the `{}` formatting button. Thanks!

Comment: Jeff, I have added the thing you have requested. Thanks!

Comment: [Cross-posted to Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/11420/278).